# Looking for some help on the Sin_domain proof from Software Foundations Color.v

Tags: coq

Here is the full module: https://softwarefoundations.cis.upenn.edu/vfa-current/Color.html

The theorem at hand:

```
Exercise: 3 stars (Sin_domain)
Lemma Sin_domain: ∀ A n (g: M.t A), S.In n (Mdomain g) ↔ M.In n g.
```

Usually, 3 stars indicates hard but not too hard, but I'm struggling to figure out how to attack this. If you unfold Mdomain it becomes a fold which then becomes M.xfoldi, which is fairly low level. I have a sense of how I could prove a bunch of low level lemmas about how xfoldi acts on various indices but...I feel like there has got to be a better way? That said it does have this disclaimer

```
This seems so obvious! But I didn't find a really simple proof of it.
```

My first instinct with this sort of thing is always try try and prove some sort of distribution principle about the thing at hand, such as

```
Mdomain (M.Node s1 o s2)
```

But since Mdomain is implemented in terms of a fold, it gets complicated pretty quickly. Again, probably not insurmountable but...I'm wondering if there is a better way (given I just spent many, many hours on Sremove_cardinal_less and Mremove_cardinal_less!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Use [`WP.fold_rec_bis`](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/stdlib/Coq.FSets.FMapFacts.html#WProperties_fun.fold_rec_bis) to prove a relation `P` between a map and the result of folding it (with `M.fold`). It is a form of induction principle:

- Base case: the relation must hold between the empty map and the initial accumulator;
- Induction step: if the relation holds of some map (and accumulator), then it holds after inserting a new key-value pair (and updating the accumulator accordingly).

As a technicality, it also requires a "compatibility" assumption (which is an explicit proof that your relation `P` is independent from the order of insertion).

```
  Theorem fold_rec_bis :
    forall (A:Type)(P : t elt -> A -> Type)(f : key -> elt -> A -> A),
     forall (i:A)(m:t elt),
     (forall m m' a, Equal m m' -> P m a -> P m' a) ->  (* Compatibility *)
     (P (empty _) i) ->                                 (* Base case *)
     (forall k e a m', MapsTo k e m -> ~In k m' ->      (* Induction step *)
       P m' a -> P (add k e m') (f k e a)) ->
     P m (fold f m i).
```

Comment: Sigh, I'm feeling very dumb but while I can see how this let's me change the form, I'm at a wall on how to massage things. For example, `S.In n (Mdomain g)` is in a hypothesis and we must prove `M.In n g` (one direction of the proof). By splitting on g and on n, I was able to get to `S.In (n~1)%positive (Mdomain (M.Node g1 o g2))` in the hypothesis and needing `S.In n (Mdomain g2)` but...am stuck on how to deal with the Mdomain. fold_rec_bis also requires P(empty _) i to be true and in this case, In n S.empty is not true. I know I need to massage it...

Comment: Ah, ok, I see now that I was overspecifying. I tried applying it to the whole proof and I think I have made progress!! Before I had split beforehand, which was overspecific.